# How to read each element in a line of text without knowing how many elements there are? (C++)

Tags: c++, readline

I couldn't find the answer to my question elsewhere, so I thought I'd make a new question. I have a text file and each line is a series of numbers. I need to add each line up. But I don't know how many elements are on each line. So something like:

> 1  2  3  3  1
>
> 3  2  1  2
>
> 2  3  1  5  2  1

should output:

> Line 1: 10
>
> Line 2: 8
>
> Line 3: 14

I know how to do this when the amount of numbers per line is known, but can't seem to figure it out otherwise. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you explain why there is output "Line 1: 13"?

Comment: Bad math, I edited it. Thanks for point it out.

Answer (score 3):

Let `file` be an `std::ifstream` object ready to use:

```
std::string line;

while (std::getline(file, line)) {  // for each line
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int i;
    while (iss >> i) {              // for each int in line
        // use i
    }
}
```

You can store integers in a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you wish. It'll grow dynamically when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach is to read a line using `std::getline()` and then decoding that line. That's a bit boring as it needs another stream. It can be done without.

The easiest way to not first read a line is probably to create a manipulator which skips whitespace but fails upon detecting a newline (`'\n'`). You would then use the manipulator, read the `int`, and if that is succcessful process the value. For example:

```
std::istream& skip_non_newline(std::istream& in) {
    for (int c; std::isspace(c = in.peek()); ) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
        else {
            in.ignore();
        }
    }
}

// ....
while (in) {
    int total = 0, value = 0;
    while (in >> skip_non_newline >> value) {
        tota += value;
    }
    if (!in.eof()) {
        in.clear(); // failure was due to a format error or a newline being hit...
        if (in.peek() != '\n') {
            in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit); // OK, not due to a newline...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work if there are trailing whitespaces other than `'\n'` on a line?

Comment: @jrok: the code is untested but I think it would work if I had used a loop... I shall correct the error.

Answer (score 0):

Take each line and store it as a stringstream, then use that to extract each element, you'll know when it's empty because the STL defines a member methed called `empty` that returns true in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

If you need simply output the sum of numbers in each line then you can do it the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

//...
std::string line;
size_t n = 0;

while ( std::getline( file, line ) )
{
    std::istringstream is( line );

    std::cout << "Line " << ++n << ": "
              << std::accumulate( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ),
                                  std::istream_iterator<int>(), 0 )
              << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works. One question, how would you add something other than ints? I've tried doubles but it prints out 0 to the console. (I know it isn't 0)

Comment: @user3426380 If you want to substitute int for double then use std::istream_iterator<double> and instead of 0 0.0 in the algorithm call.